# What type of logic do I use in this situation?

Tags: c#

I'm currently coding a console application and all I need to do is to add a menu. I understand basic if statements. How can I transfer the user to different part of the programs? Sort of like this :

```
if (menuoption == 1)
{
    // Transfer to menu option 1
}
```

What type of logic do I need to use in this circumstance ?

Comment: That depends on how your code is structured, and usually calling methods is the best bet. Can you give us some more code context?

Comment: The easiest way to implement this would be to create a new function in your class and call it. If you want code, I can create an answer.

Comment: Gunr , there has to be three options, 1 for the cost calculator, 2 for the help option, and 3 for the exit option. And when the user enters one of the numbers they will be taken to the next part of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Use switch for menus

```
//User enters a value.
var menu = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
switch(menu)
{
    case 1:
       //go to menu 1
      break;
    case 2:
       //go to menu 2
      break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! How can i change what each case is set as ? Im sort of confused aha

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a simple statemachine:

```
public enum States {State1, State2}
public States State = States.State1;

//Main:
while(true)
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case States.State1:
            //Your code for State1
            break;
        case States.State2:
            //Your code for State2
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    //Your Transitions:
    if (Input == "State1") {State = States.State1;}
    else {State = States.State2;}
}
```

Here is a small tutorial: [State Machines with C Callbacks | Code and Life](http://codeandlife.com/2013/10/06/tutorial-state-machines-with-c-callbacks/)

Answer (score 0):

How it works a console menù? In console you type something and then check if something is related to a specific function, if not the application can "Wrong selection, type again". How to accomplish this?
Well first of all the user need to write is choice at least one time so you need a `do while` cycle (yes, you could use `while(true)` or `for(;;)` but if you are learning it's a better choice use the correct cycle). Ok, now we are in `do`, get the input and pass it into `switch` (check Bewar Salah answer), after that create all `case` clauses that you need, remember to use `default` for all clauses that you don't need to manage. Once is finished the `switch` condition you are in `while`. What do you need to check in `while`? You need to check that user hasn't type the value for exit from the application (so the condition is like: `if user has not input exit continue run the application, else exit`)